# Show that if terms of a series have ratio less than the ratio of convergent series, then the series converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We have two infinite series $\sum a_n $ and $\sum b_n$, such that $a_n > 0,\ b_n > 0$ and $a_{n + 1}/a_n \leq b_{n + 1}/b_n$ for all $n$. Show that if $\sum b_n$ converges, then $\sum a_n$ also converges.

Any hints on how to prove this? I can sort of picture why this must be true, but I'm not sure how to prove this rigorously. I'm not sure using the ratio test would help here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparision test helps here. The ratio test will not work in general, as the following example shows: Let $a_n = n^{-3}$, $b_n = n^{-2}$. Then 
the ratio $a_n/a_{n+1}$ converges to 1, so the ratio test is inconclusive, but
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = \left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^3 < \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^2 = \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}} $$
for all $n$.

To prove your claim, note that 
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} < \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}} \iff
      \frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} < \frac{a_n}{b_n} $$
This gives by induction 
$$ \frac{a_n}{b_n} \le \frac{a_1}{b_1} =: M \iff a_n \le Mb_n $$
Hence, by comparision, $\sum a_n$ converges.