# How can I prove the ratio comparison test?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I prove the ratio comparison test? Given that (for all $n$) we have sequences $a_n\gt 0$ and $b_n\gt 0$ and $$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\le \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$ I want to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{b_n}$ converges if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ converges

My thought is since all the terms are positive and the series $a_n$ converges, then the sequence of successive ratios of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converge to a limit $L_1<1$. Since the sequence of successive ratios $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\le \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ then the sequence $b_n$ converges to a number $L_2$ less than $1$, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{b_n}$ converges? Any hints would be great.

Comment: Your question is missing crucial hypotheses. What do you know about $\sum a_n$?

Comment: "… since all the terms are positive and the series $a_n$ converges,  then the sequence of successive ratios of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converge to a limit $L_1<1$" ← That's not necessarily true.

Comment: @AndrewZhang whoops, I'll edit that

Comment: @zipirovich That's good to know, thank you

Comment: Given the nice proof provided by @RRL, what nice example do you have for which this test can be applied?

Comment: @Henry I don't know, do you have something in mind?

Comment: @ Cotton Headed Ninnymuggins, not for this moment, but I will try to find something.

Comment: And another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2019616/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bb_%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%7Bb_n%7D%5Cle%20%5Cfrac%7Ba_%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%7Ba_n%7D%24)

Comment: @MartinR WOW! That should be on the front page of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $b_2 \leqslant \frac{b_1}{a_1} a_2$ and by induction $b_n \leqslant \frac{b_1}{a_1} a_n$ for all $n > 1$.

Hence, the series $\sum b_n$ converges by the comparison test.

Comment: Incredibly concise, thank you. And we know $\frac{b_1}{a_1}a_n$ converges since that's just a constant multiple of a converging series (of $a_n$), right?

Comment: Yes -- $\sum_{k=1}^n b_k \leqslant \frac{b_1}{a_1} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ for all $n$.

Comment: How would I show that $b_n\le \frac{b_1}{a_1}a_n$ by induction?

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins: We have $b_{k+1} \leqslant \frac{b_k}{a_k} a_{k+1}$ for all $k \geqslant 1$ by rearranging your first inequality. So for $k=1$ we have $b_2\leqslant \frac{b_1}{a_1} a_{2}$.  Assume it holds for $k = n-1$ , that is $b_{n-1} \leqslant \frac{b_1}{a_1} a_{n-1}$ and $\frac{b_{n-1}}{a_{n-1} }\leqslant \frac{b_1}{a_1}$. Since $b_n \leqslant \frac{b_{n-1}}{a_{n-1}} a_n$ it follows that $b_n \leqslant \frac{b_1}{a_1} a_n$.

Comment: I hope Santa gets you something really nice for Christmas if you celebrate it. Thank you

Comment: If we suppose it holds for $k=n-1$ doesn't that mean "$b_{k+1}\le ...$" becomes $b_{n} \le \frac{b_1}{a_1}a_n$?

Comment: I can’t edit the comment but the “Assume it holds for $k=n-1$, that is  …” should just be “Assume the result holds for $n-1$, that is …”

Comment: I see, thank you